# Online Certification Authority, cannot Select.

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a domain server and when I reach to specify the online certification Authority, the select button is grayed out.I wish to select the same computer as its the certification authority.Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My AD CS was running fine but my IIS server just wouldn't let me select it. To doublecheck that my Certificate Authority server is up I run **certutil.exe** from CMD and I could see my CA server up and running.

I fixed it in the most canon Windows troubleshooting way. IIS restart.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this page:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversecurity/thread/e3e43894-30d5-4064-93d1-96d46ef3de14/

The answer from that thread:

*note that you can enroll certificates from IIS only from default V1 WebServer template. This template must be added to your issuing CA server.*

Comment: I tried that option , it does not help. I had earlier created another domain certificate with the same CA. I was wondering if there is a limit to number of domain certificates we can create.

Comment: Can some one help me here? I am having the same issue here? However I am not sure what my domain CA is? I simply have one server with a domain name that points to it on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and the answer "V1 WebServer template. This template must be added to your issuing CA server." did not resolve it.
But, after I ran the following in command prompt:

```
certreq -submit -attrib “CertificateTemplate:WebServer” request.req
```

my request was processes and I was issued my certificate.
In addition, I got Select button is worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to resolve this problem, from here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27758425/Windows-2008R2-IIS-7-Domain-Certficate-problem-select-button-is-greyed-out.html

> You could try enrolling the certificate through the certificates MMC
>   snap-in instead and see if you have better luck:
>
> Start -> Run -> type 'mmc' -> Press enter
>
> (MMC console should open)
>
> File -> Add/Remove Snap-in -> Select 'Certificates' -> Add -> Computer
>   Account -> Local Computer -> Click OK out of the Add/Remove Snap-ins
>   window.
>
> Expand certificates -> Expand Personal -> Right click in an empty
>   space in the main pane -> All tasks -> Request new certificate.
>
> You should be able to run through that wizard and enroll based on your
>   CA enrollment policies. Any certs that you enroll here and are
>   applicable for securing websites will appear in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

A couple more checks for those facing this issue:

- Use a domain user and not a local user
- Check if your CA is an enterprise CA